# Add Animation in the tableview rows

Tags: animation, javafx-2, tableview, geometry

Here scenario is, there are three columns in tableview Task,Group Number and Status.Task number will have string, Group number will also have String but here in status column i want to disply colour filled circles below is my code.Its not giving any error and also not showing circles.

part of xml controller class:

```
@FXML
    private TableView<TaskSchData> taskListTable = new TableView<TaskSchData>();
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TaskSchData, String> taskName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TaskSchData, String> grpNo;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TaskSchData, String> statuscheck;

taskName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TaskSchData, String>("taskName"));
        grpNo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TaskSchData, String>("grpNo"));
        statuscheck.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TaskSchData, String>("statuscheck"));

 TaskSchData taskSchData = new TaskSchData(data.gettaskName(), data.getsuffix(),circle);
```

TaskSchData class:

```
public final SimpleStringProperty taskName;
    public final SimpleStringProperty grpNo;
    public Circle status ; 
 Circle circle = new Circle(150, Color.web("red", 0.05));
    public TaskSchData(String taskName, String groupNo,Circle cir) {
        this.taskName = new SimpleStringProperty(taskName);
        this.grpNo = new SimpleStringProperty(groupNo);
        this.status=cir;

    }

    public Circle getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName.get();
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        this.taskName.set(taskName);
    }

    public void setStatus(Circle img) {
       this.status=img;
    }
public SimpleStringProperty taskNameProperty() {
        return taskName;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty grpNoProperty() {
        return grpNo;
    }
```

fxml:

```
 <TableColumn sortable="false" text="Tasks" fx:id="taskName">
                  <minWidth>
                    <Long fx:value="50" />
                  </minWidth>
                  <prefWidth>
                    <Long fx:value="150" />
                  </prefWidth>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn sortable="false" text="Group No" fx:id="grpNo">
                  <prefWidth>
                    <Long fx:value="75" />
                  </prefWidth>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Status" fx:id="statuscheck">
                  <prefWidth>
                    <Long fx:value="100" />
                  </prefWidth>
                </TableColumn>
```

Kindly help here.

Comment: Could you please study on TableColumn's CellFactory. Search the site about it, see tutorials on the net etc.

Comment: As Uluk said: CellFactory is the way to go for custom rendering. PropertyValueFactory only works for basic rendering / property.